# how to make remove repeated constant from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bunch of images and I am storing them in an array. The following method works where I am grabbing the the common url and putting it in a var and treating it like a constant. It works. But still there are repeats inside the array. I am repeating "linkCons" several times. Can I make it even shorter?

```
var linkCons = 'http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/'

var num = [linkCons+'nw0.png',linkCons+'nw1.png',linkCons+'nw2.png',linkCons+'nw3.png',linkCons+'nw4.png',linkCons+'nw5.png',linkCons+'nw6.png',linkCons+'nw7.png',linkCons+'nw8.png',linkCons+'nw9.png',];
```

Comment: Use a loop and a counter.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var num = [];
var linkCons = "http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/Numbers/";
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    num.push(linkCons + "nw" + i + ".png");
}
```